# Virtual hosts in nginx on a chromebook

Tags: google-chrome, nginx, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I develop a few webpages on my local computer. My setup is one virtual server in nginx for each site and then an entry in /etc/hosts for each site pointing an domain name to 127.0.0.1.

However I switched computer to a chromebook and can't keep this way of working anymore.

I use nginx in a crouton created debian chroot and it works fine. However chrome os won't let me edit /etc/hosts. I still reach my nginx with 127.0.0.1 but I can't reach any of my virtual servers anymore.

What's your solution to this problem? (I know that I can force edit /etc/hosts on chrome os if I disable automatic updates, I would wish to avoid this.)

Answer (score -1):

You can try a google chrome extension like this one to override dns settings: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dns-overrider/acmhaiiijfheggcaanjlgpampclpbnoh/

Comment: That rewrites the html code, not changeing the dns settings, or do I miss something?